# Cannot reference IBoutlet in cellForRowAtIndexPath from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table set up with pictures for the cells. I then want when the user clicks the cell for the picture to disappear and a few labels to show up. However, whenever I try to reference the IBoutlets from didSelectRowAtIndexPath, they are returning nil. What am I doing wrong here?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //setting up the table cell to populate the Model Data
    var moCell:modelCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("moCell") as! modelCell

    photo[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let modelImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            moCell.modelPhoto.image = modelImage

        }

    }

    return moCell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var moCell:modelCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("moCell") as! modelCell


    moCell.top.text = modelsInRange[indexPath.row]
    moCell.middle.text = "\(genNumber[indexPath.row]) Generation"
    moCell.bottom.text = "\(startYear[indexPath.row]) - \(endYear[indexPath.row])"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(id)` on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so you won't get the selected cell.

I would modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation and reload the table data. Mark some flag on your cell subclass so you can check that and on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set it up accordingly. Or even better, just reload that single cell.

A very quick sample of what i said was :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //setting up the table cell to populate the Model Data
    var moCell:modelCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("moCell") as! modelCell

    if (photo[indexPath.row].isSelected)
    {
        moCell.top.text = modelsInRange[indexPath.row]
        moCell.middle.text = "\(genNumber[indexPath.row]) Generation"
        moCell.bottom.text = "\(startYear[indexPath.row]) - \(endYear[indexPath.row])"

    } else
    {
        photo[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let modelImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                moCell.modelPhoto.image = modelImage
        }
    }
    return moCell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    photo[indexPath.row].isSelected = YES
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. You shouldn't be modifying the cell's views anywhere except the datasource method, or it'll be wrong on scrolling.

Comment: What do you mean by "modify your datasource"? Are you saying the way I have cellForRowAtIndexPath set up is wrong?

Comment: What i meant was modify the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so you check if that cell was "tapped/selected" and set what you wanted to set on selection and then update the tableview or the row in particular. i'll add more to the answer.

Comment: Check the quick sample i added. It might not work as is , but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: OK that makes sense but then I have another issue. I can't change the data in just that cell. I'll have to apply the changes to every cell.

I can definitely set a variable up telling me which row was selected, but then how would I make the changes to just that cell in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?